# Powering loads with Milwaukee M18 power tool batteries

Tags: power, circuit-design, lithium-ion, ldo

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNwj4F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to make a simple circuit to use a Milwaukee M18 18V power tool battery to power high-current loads. I want this circuit to use the power-good signal from the J2 pin of the battery to drive a N-ch PowerFET. This way the load will be disconnected if the battery's BMS detects low-voltage or over-temp. The power-good signal is 3V and only capable of ~10uA.

I've already made a working circuit by feeding the J2 pin into a logic level N-ch, which drives a high-side voltage divider to switch a P-ch, which drives a low-side voltage divider to give 10-18V to a N-ch PowerFET. This circuit has issues with: mosfets that can stay on if pull up/down resistors fail; and a high-ish voltage into the PowerFET (I'm using a IRLB3813 with Vgs(max) of 20V). There's also the problem that J2 can give 20ms pulses when turning on, and can pulse at 30ms low, 20ms high, if high currents trip the low voltage detection of the BMS. More details on the behaviour of these batteries can be seen in a video I made, but I don't show the circuit diagram, because I didn't want inexperienced people building it. It will be fairly obvious from my above description what I've done, though. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7spzrIbdKY

I want to make a much simpler circuit with as few components as possible to make it easier/safer for inexperienced people to build. I also want it to filter out pulses on the J2 signal so that it only changes state once the J2 signal has remained constant for ~60ms.

My idea is to use a fixed 12V LDO regulator with an enable pin to drive the PowerFET. I found the Nisshinbo R1154N120B to have good qualities: Vin(max) is 24V; I_in(OFF) is only 0.1uA; logic levels are good; and I'm fairly sure I_CE(ON) is less than a few uA (datasheet doesn't specify unfortunately).
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nisshinbo-micro-devices-inc/R1154N120B-TR-FE/10211795

My filter circuit should introduce a delay of 35ms between J2 going to 3V, and CE reaching 2.1V. There will also be a 70ms delay between J2 going to 0, and CE dropping to 0.3V. This will hopefully remove any startup pulses, and the bouncing that can occur when high currents trip low voltage detection. Sorry I can't explain the low voltage bounce part well - it's better explained in my video at the 5min mark.

R2 is not strictly necessary as J2 can sink current, but I want to avoid the situation of J2 getting disconnected whilst B+ and B- remain connected. D1 & R3 are also not necessary and are just to give a visual indicator that the circuit is enabled.

I can't buy the R1154N120B in my country (Australia), so I'll have to pay a lot of shipping to get it and test my circuit. So my questions before I buy are:

1. Does this seem reasonable, or have I gone down completely the wrong path? Is there an even simpler way to achieve what I want?
2. Will the LDO switch ON/OFF when the voltage passes the logic thresholds, or will it behave unpredictably in the 0.3-2.1V range?
3. If (2), then should I add a comparator or schmitt trigger or something else after my filter circuit. Is there such a device that only draws a few uA when it's in the low state?
4. Is there something better than the R1154N120B for my application, or maybe something as good but more commonly available?

Page 11 of the R1154N120B datasheet says "Do not make voltage level of chip enable pin keep floating level, or in between VIH and VIL . Unless otherwise,
Output voltage would be unstable or indefinite, or unexpected current would flow internally", but would a <100ms transition be fine? Page 2 shows the CE pin having 3 not-gates feeding into the power supply of an opamp, but I don't really understand this.

Some other options I found where the Microchip MCP1804T-C002I/OT and Texas Instruments TL751L12CDR